# Showing two statistics are independent

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, independence

> Let $T$ be a complete suﬃcient real-valued statistic for the parameter $\theta$ and $S$ be another real-valued statistic whose distribution function $F$ does not depend on the parameter $\theta$. Show that $P(S \le s\mid T)−F(s)$ equals zero almost surely under each $P_\theta$ and for each real $s$. Conclude from this that $S$ and $T$ are independent.

I'm very stuck, I don't even know where to start. I tried directly calculating $P(S \leq s\mid T)$ to get something a.s F and had no luck.  I think I'm missing a theorem or property I need.

Comment: What is $F(s) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: ok, For now I'm guessing you meant $F_S(s). \qquad$

Comment: F(s) is the CDF of the random variable S. The problem is copy/pasted. I'm not sure what your subscript S is for. if you're merely denoting the R.V which the cdf refers to, this is correct.

Comment: If $s=3$ then $F_S(s) = F_S(3) = \Pr(S\le 3).$ In the expression $F_S(3),$ the subscript tells you which random variable's c.d.f. this is. $F_S(3)$ is different from $F_U(3). \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T$ is sufficient for $\theta,$ the conditional distribution of $S$ given $T$ does not depend on $\theta.$ Therefore $\Pr(S\le s\mid T)$ does not depend on $\theta.$ By the law of total expectation, $\operatorname E(\Pr(S\le s\mid T)) = \Pr(S\le s).$ Therefore $\Pr(S\le s\mid T) - \Pr(S\le s)$ (since it can be computed without knowing the value of $\theta$) is an unbiased estimator of $0.$ By completeness of $T,$ this difference must therefore be $0$ with probability $1.$ And if $\Pr(S\le s\mid T) = \Pr(S\le s)$ for every value of $s,$ then $S$ and $T$ are independent.

This result is called Basu's theorem.